# bootstrap selectpicker setting data-max-option not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for following to get work  but none of the code is working:(

$("#comboColumnOption"+counter).selectpicker('maxOptions', '3');   //Not working

```
`$("#comboColumnOption"+counter).data("data-max-options", 3); //Not setting` up as when I click it allowed me to select more than 3 ......

    $("#comboColumnOption"+counter).selectpicker('maxOptions', '3');    $("#comboColumnOption"+counter).selectpicker('render'); //Not work
```

I am using selectpicker from this website:
http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

```
    $("#comboColumnOption"+counter).data("data-max-options", 3);
        $("#comboColumnOption"+counter).selectpicker('render'); // not working
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      maxOptions:2
  });
```

You should not use data-max-options when setting with javascript.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SE3OM5X4eiTYOoxe99Fe)

Comment: Hi Shamal thanks bro it works but can you also let me know how I can apply selectAll or deselectAll without using following as following is not working $("#comboColumnOption"+counter).selectpicker('deselectAll');

Comment: The syntax is correct. I added deselect feature in my plunker. Check your code if something is wrong with the counter variable.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
    maxOptions:2
});
```

only works once.

If you need to change maxOptions depending on some other parameter - changing maxOptions only works the first time. Subsequent calls will be ignored even if calling:

```
$( '#periodselect' ).selectpicker('refresh');
$( '#periodselect' ).selectpicker('render');
$( '#periodselect' ).selectpicker('init');
```

Here is my code:

```
if ( i == 0 && periodDisplayName != "Aggregated all" ) { 
    if ( $("#periodselect optgroup").attr("data-max-options") == "15" ) {
        $('#periodselect').selectpicker({
            maxOptions:2
        );
    }
} else if ( i == 0 ){
    if ( $("#periodselect optgroup").attr("data-max-options") == "2" ) {
        $('#periodselect').selectpicker({
            maxOptions:15
        });
        $("#periodselect optgroup").attr("data-max-options", 15);
        $('#periodselect').selectpicker('maxOptions', 15);
        $('#periodselect').selectpicker("data-max-options", 15);
        var selRefresh = $( '#periodselect' ).selectpicker('refresh');
        var selRender = $( '#periodselect' ).selectpicker('render');
        var selInit = $( '#periodselect' ).selectpicker('init');
    }
}
```

Testing it I first see that maxOption is set to 2 (from 15), then I want to see if maxOption can be set to 15 again - which it doesnt.